# Is there a way to tag page headers and footers when saving a Word doc as a PDF?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-acrobat, accessibility

My question:

Is there an automated way to add the header and footer tags without requiring document editors to do this manually in Adobe Acrobat? This needs to be scalable across hundreds if not thousands of documents, and across content creators with wildly varying ability levels.

Details follow:

If I create a Word document which has page headers and footers, then when I save the document as a PDF with accessibility tags, the headers and footers do not have tags.

There is the separate issue that some headers and footers stay constant throughout a document, while others change by section or page, in particular page number. If the solution requires that repeated content be repeated in the document tags, I suppose we would need to live with that, but ideally repeated content would not result in repeated tags and only changed header and footer content would be tagged.

This has been an issue for many years; I believe I reported it to Microsoft somewhere between 10 and 20 years ago. My supervisor expressed surprise that there hasn't been an upswelling of complaints about this given the focus on accessibility. However, when I try to search for references to this issue and any possible workarounds, I come up empty-handed.

Simply putting the header content into the body is not a feasible workaround because documents regularly get edited, causing page breaks to move about during editing. (Yes, I know that Microsoft Word has a text block feature, but that causes its own accessibility issues in terms of reading sequence, which is also an accessibility requirement.)

Steps on a computer that has Microsoft Windows 11, Microsoft Word 365 and Adobe Acrobat Pro installed:

In Word 365 desktop application for windows:

1. Start a new document
2. Double click in the header area at the top of the page
3. Type "test header"
4. Double click in the body area
5. Type "test body text"
6. Double click in the footer area at the bottom of the page
7. Type "test footer"
8. Click File then Save
9. Save the document
10. Click File then Save as Adobe PDF
11. Click Options
12. If "Enable accessibility and reflow with tagged PDF" is not checked, then check it
13. Click OK
14. If "View result" is not checked, then check it
15. Click Save
16. Wait for the file to open in Adobe Acrobat Pro.

In Adobe Acrobat Pro:

17. If the left sidebar is not expanded, then expand it
18. If the tag icon does not appear, then right click the left side bar and select Accessibility Tags
19. Click the tag icon
20. In the document itself, select the text "test body text"
21. In the accessibility tag pane, choose Find tag from selection from the drop-down menu

Expected and actual results: the tag for "test body text" is highlighted in the accessibility tag pane

22. In the document itself, select the text "test header"
23. In the accessibility tag pane, choose Find tag from selection from the drop-down menu

Expected result: a tag for "test header" is highlighted in the accessibility tag pane

Actual result: I get an error dialogue "The selection was not found"

24. In the document itself, select the text "test footer"
25. In the accessibility tag pane, choose Find tag from selection from the drop-down menu

Expected result: a tag for "test footer" is highlighted in the accessibility tag pane

Actual result: I get an error dialogue "The selection was not found"

26. In the accessibility tag pane, expand all tags using the expand icon

Expected result: there are tags for "test header", "test body text" and "test footer"

Actual result: there is a tag for "test body text" but not for any other text

### Edit - Correction

I stand corrected. The correct techniques are:

1. Word apparently intentionally does not tag headers and footers, per PDF/UA. They are instead marked as artifacts.
2. Editors need to apply page numbering in Acrobat (or some other PDF program) to ensure that the number that Acrobat uses internally for each page agrees with the number that appears visibly on the page.
3. Either the headers and footers need to be de-artifacted and tagged on the first and/or last page they appear or the content needs to be in the running document content and not the footer. For example, a header which is repeated on every page might be included on the top of the first page as content (rather than as a header) and a footer which is repeated on every page might be included on the last page as content (rather than as a footer).

So this is an authoring issue and cannot be handled automatically. That said, if there is an automated solution, I would love to hear it.

References:
[PDF14: Providing running headers and footers in PDF documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF14.html)
[PDF17: Specifying consistent page numbering for PDF documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF17.html)

Answer (score 0):

I stand corrected. The correct techniques are:

1. Word apparently intentionally does not tag headers and footers, per PDF/UA. They are instead marked as artifacts.
2. Editors need to apply page numbering in Acrobat (or some other PDF program) to ensure that the number that Acrobat uses internally for each page agrees with the number that appears visibly on the page.
3. Either the headers and footers need to be de-artifacted and tagged on the first and/or last page they appear or the content needs to be in the running document content and not the footer. For example, a header which is repeated on every page might be included on the top of the first page as content (rather than as a header) and a footer which is repeated on every page might be included on the last page as content (rather than as a footer).

So this is an authoring issue and cannot be handled automatically. That said, if there is an automated solution, I would love to hear it.

References:
[PDF14: Providing running headers and footers in PDF documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF14.html)
[PDF17: Specifying consistent page numbering for PDF documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF17.html)